# Why does Neo4j hit every indexed record when only returning a count?

Tags: solr, neo4j

I am using version 3.0.3, and running my queries in the shell.

I have ~58 million `record` nodes with 4 properties each, specifically an ID string, a epoch time integer, and lat/lon floats.

When I run a query like `profile MATCH (r:record) RETURN count(r);` I get a very quick response:

```
+----------+
| count(r) |
+----------+
| 58430739 |
+----------+
1 row
29 ms

Compiler CYPHER 3.0

Planner COST

Runtime INTERPRETED

+--------------------------+----------------+------+---------+-----------+--------------------------------+
| Operator                 | Estimated Rows | Rows | DB Hits | Variables | Other                          |
+--------------------------+----------------+------+---------+-----------+--------------------------------+
| +ProduceResults          |           7644 |    1 |       0 | count(r)  | count(r)                       |
| |                        +----------------+------+---------+-----------+--------------------------------+
| +NodeCountFromCountStore |           7644 |    1 |       0 | count(r)  | count( (:record) ) AS count(r) |
+--------------------------+----------------+------+---------+-----------+--------------------------------+

Total database accesses: 0
```

The `Total database accesses: 0` and `NodeCountFromCountStore` tells me that neo4j uses a counting mechanism here that avoids iterating over all the nodes.

However, when I run `profile MATCH (r:record) WHERE r.time < 10000000000 RETURN count(r);`, I get a very slow response:

```
+----------+
| count(r) |
+----------+
| 58430739 |
+----------+
1 row
151278 ms

Compiler CYPHER 3.0

Planner COST

Runtime INTERPRETED

+-----------------------+----------------+----------+----------+-----------+------------------------------+
| Operator              | Estimated Rows | Rows     | DB Hits  | Variables | Other                        |
+-----------------------+----------------+----------+----------+-----------+------------------------------+
| +ProduceResults       |           1324 |        1 |        0 | count(r)  | count(r)                     |
| |                     +----------------+----------+----------+-----------+------------------------------+
| +EagerAggregation     |           1324 |        1 |        0 | count(r)  |                              |
| |                     +----------------+----------+----------+-----------+------------------------------+
| +NodeIndexSeekByRange |        1752922 | 58430739 | 58430740 | r         | :record(time) < {  AUTOINT0} |
+-----------------------+----------------+----------+----------+-----------+------------------------------+

Total database accesses: 58430740
```

The count is correct, as I chose a time value larger than all of my records. What surprises me here is that Neo4j is accessing EVERY single record. The profiler states that Neo4j is using the `NodeIndexSeekByRange` as an alternative method here.

My question is, why does Neo4j access EVERY record when all it is returning is a count? Are there no intelligent mechanisms inside the system to count a range of values after seeking the boundary/threshold value within the index?

I use Apache Solr for the same data, and returning a count after searching an index is extremely fast (about 5 seconds). If I recall correctly, both platforms are built on top of Apache Lucene. While I don't know much about that software internally, I would assume that the index support is fairly similar for both Neo4j and Solr.

I am working on a proxy service that will deliver results in a paginated form (using the `SKIP n LIMIT m` technique) by first getting a count, and then iterating over results in chunks. This works really well for Solr, but I am afraid that Neo4j may not perform well in this scenario.

Any thoughts?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question exactly, but why do you need to count upfront before paginating? You can just paginate until there are no results left.

Comment: I might mention this to my team as a possible feature removal. The service I am working on is suppose to allow the user to modify their input parameters so that they can dynamically see a totalResults parameter on the fly without receiving actual result data. Without a fast mechanism to retrieve counts, this is not practical. Our current backend is Apache Solr where the specification of "rows=0" seems to perform very well (a time range query returns in a couple seconds as opposed to minutes). So I at this point I am concerned as to whether or not neo4j is an potential tool for our application.

Comment: Note than unless you've added a constraint to force the presence of the `time` property on `record` nodes, the full scan is also needed to exclude nodes which *don't* have the property and for which the `WHERE` clause is false, regardless of whether all the known values match the clause.

Comment: Ahh, thank you Frank! I'm guessing providing this constraint would likely increase the performance of range queries on the constrained variable. Unfortunately I am limited to the community edition at this time.
Just to be clear, if I were to run this scenario, the existence constraint would levy the majority of the database hits, correct? (anything that falls below/above the threshold value)

Answer (score -1):

The later query does a NodeIndexSeekByRange operation. This is going through all your matched nodes with the `record` label to look up the value of the node property `time` and does a comparison if its value is less than `10000000000`.

This query actually has to get every node and read some info for comparison, and that's the reason why it is much slower.

Comment: Why would it be comparing the value of time on every node though? The index should seek nodes on the boundary where `time = 10000000000`, and then proceed to collect requested information on every node that follows this threshold in the index (where `time > 10000000000`). Since `count` does not request any information, this should (optimally) only involve a counter that does not "hit" the actual data.
I've investigated this issue all day, and I did run into this: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/2260
Seems like this is an issue that has not been resolved.